# Android onClick double method

Tags: android, button, onclick

I would like to know a simple thing. I have 2 methods, and if there is a TextView string "ok" the onClick event should call out method 1, however if the string in a TextView is "no" the onClick event should call the method 2. How can I do this? 
thanks

Comment: Are these "strings" something the user enters or that you have defined? Can you explain your situation a little better?

Comment: no, strings are not dynamic but defined by me. The user can only choose one or the other

Comment: I once had a class where we learned to check y/n and only checked the first character and we used case insensitive checking so answers like no nah nope yes yeah yah would work.  Seems like you'd be better off with with a ok/cancel button dialog fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use setTag on the textView. when onClick is fired. You can use getTag and cast it to a string and compare. Depending on the result, call different method

before you set a listener to your textview.

```
tv.setTag("ok");
tv2.setTag("no");
```

in your on click listener.

```
public void onClick(View v){
  String tag = (String) v.getTag();
  if (tag.equals("ok"){
    callMethod1();
  } else if (tag.equals("no")){
    callMethod2();
  }
}
```

Comment: you give an example? was the first time that I have to deal with this thing